# Almost Everywhere Function Space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory, topological-vector-spaces

**Problem**

Let $\Omega$ be a measure space with measure $\mu$ and $V$ a topological vector space not necessarily Hausdorff as well as the function space $\mathcal{F}:=\{f:\Omega\to V\}$ topologized by pointwise convergence.

Consider the quotient $\mathcal{F}_\mu:=\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{N}_\mu$ by the subspace $\mathcal{N}_\mu:=\{f:\Omega\to V\:f=0\text{ $\mu$a.e.}\}$.

**Questions**

Is $\mathcal{F}_\mu$ a topological vector space?

If $V$ was Hausdorff, is $\mathcal{F}_\mu$ Hausdorff then?

**Attempt**

Obviously, the subspace divided out is closed. Does this imply Hausdorff here and if so then why?

Comment: Wikipedia answers both questions: Let $X$ be a topological vector space. Given a subspace $M \subset X$, the quotient space $X/M$ with the usual quotient topology is a Hausdorff topological vector space if and only if $M$ is closed. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space#Topological_structure They point out in a footnote that this follows from the fact that a topological vector space is Hausdorff if and only if the set $\{ 0 \}$ is closed, and $\{ 0 \} \subset X/M$ is closed in the quotient topology if and only if $M$ was closed in the topology of $X$.

Comment: Dear @Ian: Would you mind giving this as answer so I can check it off? I would appreciate it. *(Copy-Paste is ok.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space#Topological_structure) answers both of your questions. Specifically, let $X$ be a topological vector space and $M \subset X$ be a subspace. Then $X/M$ in its usual topology is Hausdorff if and only if $M$ is closed. This is essentially because a topological vector space is Hausdorff if and only if $\{ 0 \}$ is closed, and $\{ 0 \}$ is closed in $X/M$ if and only if $M$ is closed in $X$.